# UK number format

Tags: notation, article-writing

I am a foreign student preparing for UK exams in maths and am confused by number formats I should use.

(1) While studying the US, my teacher sometimes considered my number $1$ to be $7$ as I wrote a diagonal line, which is not normally used in the US ([see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epGpX.jpg)). How are these digits, as well as $4$, normally written in the UK?

(2) In my language, we never say *and* in long numbers, which is opposite in English. If $1,234,567$ is pronounced as 'one million, two hundred *and* thirty-four thousand, five hundred *and* sixty-seven' (i.e. 'and' is not used between units and thousands, thousands and millions, etc.), how to pronounce long numbers containing zeros correctly, e.g.:

- $12,005$ = twelve thousand *(and?)* five
- $12,050$ = twelve thousand *(and?)* fifty
- $12,500$ = twelve thousand *(and?)* five hundred.

(3) Is it the correct notation for recurring decimals in the UK?

$1.22345634563456... = 1.22$$\dot3$$45$$\dot6$

How is this number normally pronounced, 'one point two two *(and?)* three four five six repeating / repeated / recurring / recurred / into infinity'?

Comment: I like this question, but I think the tag is not so relevant. Maybe add the "notation" tag?

Comment: I agree. The tag has been edited.

Comment: +1 for preparing in advance, and good luck. I'll let the more qualified answer, will just note that I've seen $4$ handwritten as $\mathcal{4}$ in the US quite often (along the alternative you posted).

Comment: Your question on recurring decimals is correct, I would use that notation. In terms of the previous pronunciation question, I would say *and* in the first two bullets, not in the third.

Comment: Thank you all. Bacon, and how would you pronounce this recurring decimal?

Comment: Personally, I would say "one point two, two, three recurring, four, five, six recurring"

Answer (score 0):

The "continental" 7 is frequently used in the UK and widely recognised. That is the 7 with the [line through it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7#Evolution_of_the_glyph)

The number 1 is normally a vertical stroke. The diagonal stroke at the top of a 1 is not used at all in the UK.

The number 4 is hand written as the ["open 4".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4#Evolution_of_the_glyph)

How numbers are "said" in the UK tends to be as follows:

- 12,005 = twelve thousand and five
- 12,050 = twelve thousand and fifty
- 12,500 = twelve thousand five hundred
- 12,555 = twelve thousand five hundred and fifty five

Your recurring decimals format looks correct, but not something I use much. The example number: 1.22345634563456 would be said as:

One point two two three four five six three four five six recurring.